# This code is printing an array with 0 0 0 0 0 5 and not the expected array

Tags: java, arrays

```
class ArrayPrint {

    static void arrayPrinter(int[] x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(x[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... S) {

        int[] x = {3, 3, 4, 2, 7};
        x = new int[5];
        arrayPrinter(x);
        System.out.println(x.length);
    }
}
```

The expected array is not printing, it is instead printing `0 0 0 0 0`. What could be the error?

Comment: What do you think this assignment - `x = new int[5];` does?

Comment: You assigned an empty array to X and then printed it.  Arrays are initialized to zero.

Comment: Not arrays are initialized to zeros, `int` variables are.

Comment: @IngoBürk - Local variables, `int` or otherwise, are not implicitly initialized -- if you don't initialize them the compiler will reject your program.  Object fields and array elements *are* initialized to zero (or to null for references).

Comment: Yes, not local variables. But a class member of type `int`, if accessed in some method, will implicitly be initialized to `0`. My point was that what gets initialized in this situation is not the array, but the elements of the array. Arrays themselves (i.e. `private int[] myArray;` without any assignment will be implicitly initialized to `null` (not locally, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] x = {3,3,4,2,7};
x = new int[5]; // re-initializing
```

You are re-initializing the array. By default, the element values in the new array will all be 0.

Just remove the

```
x = new int[5];
```

This notation

```
int[] x = {3,3,4,2,7};
```

Creates an int array of size 5, with the element values you've specified.

Comment: Thanks for the fastest answer. Thanks to all the other responders as-well.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = new int[5];
```

Re-initializes your array to all zeroes. Remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

You are re initialized `x` array with the statement

```
x = new int[5];
```

By default, the values of array will be 0.That is the reason you are getting the output.
So remove it

```
public static void main(String...S) {    
      int[] x = {3,3,4,2,7};
      arrayPrinter(x);
      System.out.println(x.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are re-initializing the array to 0, 0, 0,0.

When you write int[] x = {3,3,4,2,7}; it initializes the array with your desired values, but in the next line you overwrite it with a "new" int[5], therefore five 0's

Answer (score 1):

you are re-initializeing your array, you should either use

```
int[]x = new int[5];
x[0] = 3;
x[1] = 3;
// and the rest of your array
```

OR

```
int[]x = {3,3,...};
```

then you can print your array,

try

```
import java.util.*;
// ... some code
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```